# Maven unable to download from remote repository

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build a Maven module that depends on SVNKit.

So my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>tmatesoft-releases</id>
        <url>http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When I try to do a mvn clean install, it looks like it attemps to look into a Nexus repository, and obviously cannot find it. I'm obviously trying to download the artifact from a remote repository at: http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases

I took a look at my settings.xml file in my ~/.m2/ folder and I see that there is a mirror that looks like this:

```
<mirror>
<!--This sends everything else to /public -->
<id>nexus</id>
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>

<url>http://Our_Nexus_Repository</url>
</mirror>
```

I thought that, if you define a `<reposotiry>` tag, your module's pom.xml will take precedence over what's defined in your settings.xml file.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

this is because the mirror will mirror all the repositories, : `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>`

you can change replace it like this : `<mirrorOf>*,!tmatesoft-releases</mirrorOf>`

more info please visit : http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Comment: @Alex if the answer helps then I would suggest rewarding the response by accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

With the way that you're using the mirror statement in your settings.xml, you're directing maven to always go to your repository.  If that is indeed the behavior that you wish, you should create a proxy for the tmatesoft-releases repository inside your nexus installation.

A common methodology for doing this is to setup a repository group for all releases you wish to have on your nexus installation.  Then just add proxy repos to the group as needed, and users won't need to change their settings.xml to instantly have visibility to the new repos you add.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Michael! What's strange is that I added it to our our Nexus repo as a Proxy, just as you said, but when I try to make push to our public repository, it doesn't seem to pick up on it...strange.